# OpenApi Generator Golang - Adding headers to request ending up in query params how to fix?

Tags: go, openapi-generator

I'm trying to generate a go client but the generator won't recognise a header and won't let me pass it to the server as a header - instead it's sent as a query param.

```
info:
  title: API
  version: "1.2"
servers:
  - url: https://example.com
paths:
  /ping:
    get:
      summary: Checks if the server is alive
      parameters:
        - in: header
          name: X-Request-ID
          schema:
            type: string
            format: uuid
          required: true
      responses:
        '200':
          description: Request has been successful
          content:
            application/json:
              schema:
                type: object
                properties:
                  returned_url:
                    type: string
```

And here is the generator I am using:

```
# https://github.com/OpenAPITools/openapi-generator/blob/master/docs/generators/go.md
docker run --rm -v "${PWD}:/local" openapitools/openapi-generator-cli generate \
  -i /local/spec.yaml \
  -g go \
  -o /local/internal/infrastructure/sdk \
  -p enumClassPrefix=true \
  -p generateInterfaces=true \
  -p isGoSubmodule=true \
  -p packageName=sdk
```

You'll notice it generates this line which adds the value of the header I pass to the query params:

```
parameterAddToQuery(localVarQueryParams, "X-Request-ID", r.xRequestID, "")
```

Is this a bug? What can I do about this?

Comment: This looks like a bug in the go template https://github.com/OpenAPITools/openapi-generator/blob/4487042f0d4ef1f4686950f0c1ddac6fe6d44f98/modules/openapi-generator/src/main/resources/go/api.mustache#L243-L252

It should be similar to how its done in the Java template:  https://github.com/OpenAPITools/openapi-generator/blob/4487042f0d4ef1f4686950f0c1ddac6fe6d44f98/modules/openapi-generator/src/main/resources/Java/api.mustache#L89-L91

Comment: @BrianPursley you might want to post that as an answer.

Comment: I was concerned it wasn't detailed enough to be a full answer, but I posted it as an answer in case it helps someone else who stumbles upon this problem.  Hopefully someone sends a pull request to fix it soon.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This looks like a bug in the go template:
https://github.com/OpenAPITools/openapi-generator/blob/4487042f0d4ef1f4686950f0c1ddac6fe6d44f98/modules/openapi-generator/src/main/resources/go/api.mustache#L243-L252

It should be similar to how its done in the Java template:
https://github.com/OpenAPITools/openapi-generator/blob/4487042f0d4ef1f4686950f0c1ddac6fe6d44f98/modules/openapi-generator/src/main/resources/Java/api.mustache#L89-L91

Comment: should be fixed now for go, https://github.com/OpenAPITools/openapi-generator/pull/14637, but I am running into the similar issue for typescript-axios generator